# Mixing WPF with a WinForm application?

Tags: wpf, winforms

My fairly large WinForm application needs a GUI overhaul, but I can't afford to do it all at once. I need to know if I can slowly add WPF into it, and if so, how?

Can I add WPF dialogs?

Can I add WPF 'panels' within a WinForm so that I can embed WPF elements?

**EDIT**

Can I do the opposite and put WinForm dialogs in my WPF application?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Put WPF control into a Windows Forms Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053501/put-wpf-control-into-a-windows-forms-form)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can host WPF controls in your WinForms applications:

[Walkthrough: Hosting a 3-D WPF Composite Control in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms745781(v=vs.100).aspx)

[Walkthrough: Hosting a Composite WPF Control in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms742215(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: 2nd link is now broken.  There's a reason we don't like link-only answers here.

Comment: Even first link is no longer available now :(

Comment: @Pankaj - I've updated the links (changed the second altogether) so that they work now. If I have time, I'll come back and update with an example.

Answer (score 6):

Yep, I've successfully mixed winforms and WPF. I even managed to add WPF windows to win32 apps, changed this app to a dll and used a WPF app to show win32 windows which show WPF windows.

To host WPF windows in WinForm or win32 apps you will need this line befor you .Show() your WpfWindow:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(myWpfWindow);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348549.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ElementHost control found in the System.Windows.Forms.Integration namespace. You will need a reference to the WindowsFormsIntegration assembly (in WindowsFormsIntegration.dll)

This control is an empty container into which you can put WPF controls e.g.

```
myElementHost.Child = someWpfControl;
```

You can find it in your toolbox and drag and drop it onto a winform like any other control;

[image]