# How can I get a full 8-bit alpha transparent Form window

Tags: .net, winforms, transparency, paint

What do I do to have a Form that is drawn using 8 bits of transparency at each pixel (using PNG files) so that I can have pixels that are 100% what I draw, ones that are 100% from what is below me, and ones that are blended.

The blended part means I cannot use Form.TransparencyKey.

Answer (score 0):

WinForms support for transparency is horrible.

If at all possible, consider writing this part of you application using WPF.  You can integrate WPF into a WinForms app.  See:

[Mixing WPF with a WinForm application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685142/mixing-wpf-with-a-winform-application)

Comment: We looked at that. Unfortunately that's a gigantic hack for where we need this.