# Inserting a winform control into WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

We have a legacy library that was created in Windows forms. we would like to use this library in an existing WPF application. According to [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx) it is possible. Has any one tried to do this? What are the caveats we need to look for? Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mixing WPF with a WinForm application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685142/mixing-wpf-with-a-winform-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many sources available on the subject. Here are a few returned *from a simple Google search*:

- [Walkthrough: Hosting a Windows Forms Control in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Hosting a Windows Forms Control in WPF by Using
  XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742875.aspx)
- [Mixing WPF and WinForms](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/mixing-wpf-and-winforms/)
- [Mixing WPF with a WinForm application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685142/mixing-wpf-with-a-winform-application)

I'll explain the first link as it's fairly straightforward and easy to manage. There's actually not much code to it.

First you need to add a reference to the following assemblies:

- WindowsFormsIntegration
- System.Windows.Forms

Then create a grid (in this case named Grid1).

Here's the code-behind:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    // Create the interop host control.
    System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host =
        new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();

    // Create the MaskedTextBox control.
    MaskedTextBox mtbDate = new MaskedTextBox("00/00/0000");

    // Assign the MaskedTextBox control as the host control's child.
    host.Child = mtbDate;

    // Add the interop host control to the Grid 
    // control's collection of child controls. 
    this.grid1.Children.Add(host);
}
```

All you're doing is instantiating a `WindowsFormsHost` then adding a child control named mtbDate. Instantiate your own control and add it using the same method instead. Then just manipulate it as you normally would in Win Forms.

Then add a using at the top of the class:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

I hope that helps.